# Unable to auto livestream when booting - enable .service does not work (failed to enable unit: Invalid argument)

Tags: boot, camera, services, raspberry-pi-os

I want to set up a service that starts a livestream when booting the rasp. I have been following this tutorial: domoticproject.com/creating-raspberry-pi-service

This is what my .service in /lib/system/system looks like

```
vi /home/pi/scripts/livestream/livestream.service

[Unit]
Description=Raspberry Livestream
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/scripts/livestream/livestream.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/scripts/livestream/
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
Type=simple
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

starting the livestream with

```
sudo systemctl start livestream.service
```

works fine.

I tried to enable the .service to make it start when booting with

```
sudo systemctl enable livestream.service
```

but that gives me the following error:

```
failed to enable unit: File livestream.service: Invalid argument
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Is `vi /home/pi/scripts/livestream/livestream.service` really part of your service file? If that's the case you should remove it and try again

Comment: that actually did the job! works well, great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vi /home/pi/scripts/livestream/livestream.service` is a command to start an editor (vi).
It should not be in the service file itself.

Remove it and try to enable the service again.

Answer (score 2):

There are some things wrong with your Unit. First you write, your .service is located in `/lib/system/system/`. If this isn't a typo then this directory isn't managed by **systemd**. This is `/lib/systemd/system` but should not be used for your custom service. This directory is reserved for systemd and for services from a distributor. Services there have lower priority and can be overlaid with custom scripts. So you should not use this directory. The best is to let systemd manage your Unit file with its commands. It is not a good idea to fiddle direct with the systemd management directories.

Then your Unit file has some unneeded entries. in general it it always the best to let systemd manage its services itself as most as possible. `StandardOutput=inherit` and `StandardError=inherit` is default so you should not use it. Then I do not see why to `Restart=always`. A proper service do not need to be restarted and to fix a buggy service with it really does not help. It's only a waste of resources to endless try to restart a crashing service. `Type=simple` is default and not needed.

First revert the configuration you have done. Then check if your script is running from the command line:

```
rpi ~$ /bin/bash /home/pi/scripts/livestream/livestream.sh
```

If this works without errors, then you should create your service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit livestream.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Raspberry Livestream
After=network-online.target

[Service]
User=pi
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/scripts/livestream/
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/pi/scripts/livestream/livestream.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Enable, start and manage it as usual, e.g. with `sudo systemctl --full edit livestream.service`.